# Display all Fields from a Form in a View in Lotus Script or Lotus Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Is there any easy way to create a view with all available fields from a form?

I have a form with over 100 fields and to create a view with all fields will take too much time. The aim is to export the data once it's in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `View` by using [`NotesDatabase.CreateView`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATEVIEW_METHOD_DB.html) method, and create columns to this `View` by using [`NotesView.CreateColumn`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATECOLUMN_METHOD_VIEW.html). The list of all fields in `Form` you can get from [`NotesForm.Fields`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FIELDS_PROPERTY.html) property. The `Form` itself you can get from [`NotesDatabase.GetForm`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFORM_METHOD.html) method.
Here is example:

```vb
Dim ses As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim form As NotesForm   
Dim view As NotesView

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase

formName$ = "YourFormName"

Set form = db.GetForm(formName$)

Set view = db.CreateView(formName$ & "Fields", {Form = "} & formName$ & {"})

Forall field In form.Fields
    Call view.CreateColumn(, field, field)
End Forall
```

Comment: Thanks, this did more or less the trick. Just one question though, it loops through fine but I get duplicate columns created. It seems that when it reaches the bottom, it continues from the top again but not the entire form. Any idea why that is?

Comment: A problem with this approach is that Views present the content of Items in Documents which may not be the same as the Fields on the Form used to create and/or display the documents. Computed for Display fields will not be on the documents and items not on the form might be added by code in the Form or Agents.

Comment: @CinNL1 There is something wrong with your code. You can try to use `Arrayunique` to remove duplicates: `fields = Arrayunique(form.Fields) : Forall field In fields : Call view.CreateColumn(, field, field) : End Forall`.

Comment: @Newbs The question is about the easy way. Sure, there are can be more complex way which takes into account the `Computed for Display` fields or even `Computed Subform` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could open a document created with the form and iterate thorugh the NotesItems. There you can get the field names.

The code could looks something like this:

```
Dim field List As String

Forall i in doc.Items
    field(i.Name) = i.Text
End Forall
```

You now have a list containing the text representation of the field as value and the name of the field as the list tag.

Or you could do this on each document and export all the values like that. Creating a view with 100 columns would create a huge view index. Not a great idea.

Comment: But note: the question is about all the fields on a form, and a list of all the fields in a document is not the same.

Comment: That is of course true. Then CinNL1 could loop through all documenst and do the same thing, add the field names to a global list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you use

ReadViewEntries
Use this command to access view data in XML form without appearance attributes such as fonts, list separators, date formats, HTML settings, view templates and frame redirections.
Syntax:

```
http://Host/Database/ViewName?ReadViewEntries
```

Link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/